# Quando inicio meu projeto android no eclipse a soluçao já vem com erros

Tags: android, eclipse

Quando inicio um projeto no eclipse a minha solução já vem com erros. Como faço para concertar isso?

[image: Erro do Eclipse]

Existe alguma maneira de eu corrigir isto de uma vez por todas?

**Edit:** Codigo do erro: Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
error: Error parsing XML: no element found  abc_activity_chooser_view_list_item.xml /appcompat_v7/res/layout    line 17 Android AAPT Problem

[image: Codigo]

Comment: Ne verdade, o erro de "R cannot be resolved to a variable" significa que os `resources` não foram "compilados" (quando o resource é compilado, ele gera uma classe chamada R), devido ao erro de parsing "Error parsing XML: no element found" e "Premature end of file". Inclua na pergunta esse arquivo XML.

Comment: Pela imagem tenho a impressão que o erro ocorre no XML de um arquivo que começa com `"abc_activity_chooser_view_list_ite..."` que pertence à biblioteca `appcompat_v7` (que teoricamente não deveria apresentar erros). Será que não é um daqueles problemas que se resolve com um clear no projeto?

Comment: Acho que um clean não vai funcionar nesse caso. Eu recomendaria reinstalar o `Support Libraries` e o `Support Libraries Repository` usando o SDK Manager. Pode ter ocorrido alguma corrupção nos dados ao baixa-los.

Comment: Entao se em ultimo caso se nao funcionar, sera que se eu desinstalar tudo e dps reinstalar ira funcionar normalmente?

Answer (score 1):

Siga as instuções aqui [Support Library Setup](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) e adicione as *libraries* referentes ao [v7-appcompat](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat).
Siga os passos para fazer o download das *libraries*, caso você ainda não o tenha feito, depois siga as instruções em *Adding libraries with resources*.